# How can I set Invitee in Google Calendar through Python?

Tags: python, google-apps

I am Setting Google Calendar via python command like this

```
def _InsertQuickAddEvent(self, 
  content="Tennis with dddddd on 5/19/2010 4am-5:30am"):
"""Creates an event with the quick_add property set to true so the content
is processed as quick add content instead of as an event description."""
event = gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry()
who = whois("himanshu.sojitra@searce.com")
event.content = atom.Content(text=content)
event.quick_add = gdata.calendar.QuickAdd(value='true');    
new_event = self.cal_client.InsertEvent(event, 
    '/calendar/feeds/default/private/full')
return new_event
```

this code is given by Google API
Can any one suggest what to do to add invitee in this?
Important links for that
http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got after lots of Research in this.....

```
event_audit=gdata.calendar.AttendeeStatus("http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.invited")
event.who.append(gdata.calendar.Who(email="xyz@pqr.com",rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.invited"))
```